Trying to scrape a website with Selenium Python and I am not able to find the elements of a table
I am trying to learn Python and one of the things I really thought to be cool is scrapping website data. I came across multiple websites where I was able to scrape data from tables just fine, but this one is not returning any results when I check how many elements return - https://www.nyse.com/ipo-center/recent-ipo.
Any feedback would be great as I am just starting to code in Python and this is just one website that I came across that when I tried it did not work.
Here is my code with the website attempted:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

driver.get("https://www.nyse.com/ipo-center/recent-ipo")

print(len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,      "/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")))

driver.quit()

Here is the result:
c:.../pythonProject/.venv/webscrapper.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56919/devtools/browser/65057eec-4e00-4936-abde-62df4be67eea

0

In Inspect Mode for Chrome, I see one result returned when I tried the same XPath from the browser:
enter image description here
I tested shortening the XPath to this:
print(len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/table/tbody")))

and that returns 1 result which is correct:
c:.../pythonProject/.venv/webscrapper.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57482/devtools/browser/dfe58545-8271-4278-95a2-ee423b7c6103

1

I am thinking there is something extra going on for this website that does not allow me to scrape or I am doing something right. Can someone help me with this, please? Is there a better way to code this as well?

Simply add a time.sleep(3) statement between driver.get() and actually pulling results from the table.  Some items are loaded with JavaScript and require some pause time for them to load in.  Tested out your exact code but with a sleep statement and it worked as you want it too.  Best of luck with your project.

The reason your code is printing 0 is because your code was too fast to execute. In other words, before even the web page could fully load, your code was executed. Hence it did not locate the target element.
Having said the above, I suggest you read and get used to below things:

Selenium's waits - Waiting strategy in your code will help effectively locate the web elements.

What is the difference between absolute and relative xpaths? Which is preferred in Selenium automation testing? - Try to understand about relative XPaths and try to use it in your code.


Check the working code below to scrape the "Largest 10 IPOs table:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.nyse.com/ipo-center/recent-ipo")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@data-testid='largest-10']//tbody//tr")))

for e in table:
    print(e.text)

Result:
10/23/2024 9/30/2024 Ingram Micro Holding Corp Technology MS, GS, JPM, BAML, DB, EVERCORE, JEFFER, RBC 11.8 10.6 Within 470,580,000
10/10/2024 9/18/2024 Upstream Bio, Inc. Healthcare JPM, TDSEC, PIPERSAND, WBLAIR 29.4 56.3 Within 293,250,000
10/24/2024 10/2/2024 Septerna, Inc. Healthcare JPM, TDSEC, CFCO, WFC 18.9 42.3 Within 288,000,000
10/10/2024 8/26/2024 Ceribell, Inc. (US) Healthcare BAML, JPM 47.1 63.4 Within 207,348,473
10/25/2024 7/26/2024 WeRide Inc. Consumer Goods MS, JPM, CICC, BKCHINA, BNPPAR, TIGERBRONZ 6.8 0.1 Within 120,007,200
10/10/2024 9/20/2024 CAMP4 Therapeutics Corporation Healthcare JPM, LEER , PIPERSAND, WBLAIR -2.5 -17.3 Below 75,020,000

Process finished with exit code 0

